# getting image size when image zoomed by user

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiimageview

how can i get the image size when it's zoomed by user, 
i write these on my project :

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 return imageView;
}
-(void) didLoad{
 UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage      imageNamed:@"image.jpg"]];
 self.imageView = tempImageView;
 [tempImageView release];

 scrollMapView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
 scrollMapView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
 scrollMapView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
 scrollMapView.clipsToBounds = YES;
 scrollMapView.delegate = self;
 [scrollMapView addSubview:imageView];
}
```

i just want to know the image size when it zoomed.. thank you.

Comment: Do you mean, if a 200x400 image is shown at 2x, you want something that returns 400x800?

Comment: yeah, something like that.. btw i've got it.. thnx bro.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can do just:

```
newZoomedWidth = scrollView.zoomScale * imageView.frame.size.width
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong about this (I'm not an iPhone developer), but I don't think the image itself gets zoomed; it's only the scroll view's display of the image view that gets zoomed. So, it's only a property of the scroll view that changes; the image remains unchanged.

That means you should be able to just [get the image view's image](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImageView/image) and [ask that for its size](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/size).

If you want the image's zoomed size rather than its original size, get its original size and multiply both dimensions by [the scroll view's zoom scale](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/zoomScale).